# Laravel 8, User already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, mysql-connector

I'm getting this error sometimes on my website

User **** already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

i've talked to the company i used for hosting and they said they have a max number of 5 connections set for all their shared plan, only way to increase it is by upgrading to a VPS which would cost a lot

is there a way to limit the number of connections in laravel?